# Public/private method signatures in Java interfaces

Tags: java, class, interface

This is a homework question about the comparing interfaces and classes in Java.

I know that interfaces don't have method implementation or instance variables but classes do.

But is it true that Java interfaces only have public method signatures whereas in classes you have have both public and private method signatures when you implement the interface?

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) resource seem to make me think so.

Comment: In addition, since Java 8 Interfaces can have default methods, which are implementations.

Comment: Have you tried t? Put a private method into an interface and you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces don't have private members.

> "The Java programming language provides mechanisms for access control, to prevent the users of a package or class from depending on unnecessary details of the implementation of that package or class."

Access control is all about masking implementation details. Interfaces have no implementation (excluding default methods, which were [introduced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in Java 8).

Conversely, a class can have public, private, or protected members since a class is implementation code.

That said, this is due to change in [Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213) when private members are going to be allowed in interfaces.